# Canvas position based on another element

Tags: wpf, canvas

Basically I want a `Canvas` to act like a `StackPanel`.  So how do set the `Canvas.Top=""` based on `Canvas.Bottom` of another element?

Background:  Trying to make an `Expander` that when expanded it will go over other elements.  Figured using a `Canvas` `ZIndex` would be the best way to do this.  So I created this:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
    <Canvas Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MyExpander}">
        <Expander Panel.ZIndex="1" Name="MyExpander" Header="Header"  >
            <StackPanel Background="LightGray">
                <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
                <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
        <StackPanel Panel.ZIndex="0" Canvas.Top="20" Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <Button Content="Button1" />
            <Button Content="Button2" />
            <Button Content="Button3"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

Now this works perfectly the problem is that `Canvas.Top="20"` is hardcoded into the XAML.  So that means if the font gets increased (the user increased font sizing in Windows) then part of the `StackPanel` will be under the `Expander`.  I tried this:

```
Canvas.Bottom="{Binding (Canvas.Bottom),ElementName=MyExpander}"
```

The issue being is that value for for `Canvas.Bottom` for `MyExpander` is `NaN` so that isn't going to work.

FYI if there is a better way to do the `Expander` expands over top of elements I am open to that as well.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well this doesn't seem like the greatest answer but it worked for me.

```
    foreach (var exp in MyCanvas.Children)
    {
       Expander ep = (Expander)exp;
       double h = ep.ActualHeight;
       Canvas.SetTop(ep, y);
       y = y + h + 20;
    }
```

Should note it goes without saying that `foreach` loop is a bit more complicated due to correct parsing of the objects in the `MyCanvas`